# Finding the shortest path in 2D Euclidean space with Cartesian coordinates with the Lagrangian

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation

I would like to get an explanation about this specific step where $\delta S$ is formulated as [at this point in this presentation](https://youtu.be/mc-Y4CmE7R4?t=2603):

$$\begin{align}
S&=\int dS=\int\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2}d\lambda\\[2ex]
\delta S &=\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} \frac 1 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\dot x^2 +\dot y^2}}\left(2\dot x\delta \dot x + 2\dot y\delta \dot y\right) d\lambda
\end{align}$$

where $x$ and $y$ are parametrized by $\lambda.$ And hence, $dx =\dot x d\lambda$ and $dy=\dot y d\lambda.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will re-derive the equations above. I hope you will forgive me; I will use notation that is clearer I believe.

The idea is to set the first variation, the perturbation of your path along some other path, say $\gamma(\lambda)=(\gamma_1(\lambda),\gamma_2(\lambda))$, to $0$. This means
$$
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg\vert_{\epsilon=0}S((x(\lambda)+\epsilon \gamma_1(\lambda),
y(\lambda)+\epsilon \gamma_2(\lambda))=0
$$
Where $S$ is the arclength functional (this is his $\delta S$). It might help to compare this to the directional derivative of multivariable calculus, where here our direction is some other curve. So, computing 
$$
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg\vert_{\epsilon=0}S((x(\lambda)+\epsilon \gamma_1(\lambda),
y(\lambda)+\epsilon \gamma_2(\lambda))\\
=
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg\vert_{\epsilon=0}\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}
\sqrt{(\dot{x}+\epsilon\gamma_1)^2+(\dot{y}+\epsilon\gamma_2)^2}\mathrm d\lambda
$$
Differentiating inside with respect to $\epsilon$ and setting to $\epsilon=0$, we get 
$$
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg\vert_{\epsilon=0}S((x(\lambda)+\epsilon \gamma_1(\lambda),
y(\lambda)+\epsilon \gamma_2(\lambda))\\
=
\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg\vert_{\epsilon=0}\sqrt{(\dot{x}+\epsilon\dot{\gamma_1})^2+(\dot{y}+\epsilon\dot{\gamma_2})^2}\mathrm d\lambda\\
=\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}\frac{\dot{\gamma_1}\dot{x}+\dot{\gamma_2}\dot{y}}
{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}\mathrm d\lambda\\
$$
Where our $\dot{\gamma_1},\dot{\gamma_2}$ is his $\delta \dot{x},\delta \dot{y}$ respectively.

Now you can integrate by parts, and argue that if the above is to hold for any perturbation $\gamma(\lambda)$, then 
$$
0=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}=
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}
$$
and so by integrating
$$
c_1=\frac{\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}\\
c_2=\frac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}
$$
and dividing the two equations (assuming $\dot{x}\ne 0$), 
$$
c=\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}\implies \dot{y}=c\dot{x}\implies y(\lambda)=cx(\lambda)+d
$$
And the original path is a straight line. If $\dot{x}=0$, then it is a vertical straight line.